# Trying to use function in excel for my data and need help trying to do include alternate possibilities

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2007

I am trying to use the `IF` function in excel 2007 for a project I am working on. I have a data set that I am subtracting cell `A1` with cell `A2` and then dividing cell `A2` by the answer.

My problem is, these are numbers being auto summed, so I was able to fix part of my problem, which was, when `A1` was 0 and `A2` was 0 to make the answer (-) using this formula `=IFERROR((C41-C42)/C42,"        -")`.

The problem I am having is I need to also include something for when `A1` is 0 and `A2` is greater than 0 (1,2,3...) that the answer becomes 0 rather than a (-) or (-100.00%).

Any help on how I would write this?

Thanks,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Not a programming question I think, but you can use something like this in your formula:

```
= IF(A1 > 0, IF(A2 > 0, "Both > 0", "A1 > 0"), IF(A2 > 0, "A2 > 0", "Both <= 0"))
```